# Meaning of Xamarin debug output of GC

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I running application written in C# Xamarin for Android(Target framework android 8.1) and get log messages like this, when debugging physical device:

```
09-20 08:53:04.165 D/Mono    (25500): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.14ms
09-20 08:53:04.165 D/Mono    (25500): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 2.53ms, stw 3.56ms promoted 40K major size: 13040K in use: 10738K los size: 40968K in use: 38154K
09-20 08:53:04.617 D/Mono    (25500): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
09-20 08:53:04.621 D/Mono    (25500): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 91 xref 1 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.10ms tarjan 0.12ms scc-setup 0.20ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.00ms
```

Do somebody know a documentation to this?

eg.: **GC_MINOR**: what `time` means? What `stw` means? What `size` means? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the mono documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/#inside-the-nursery)

> Objects are initially allocated in a nursery using a fast bump-pointer technique. When the nursery is full we start a nursery collection: this is performed with a copying GC.

- `time` is *probably* the time to garbage collection took
- `stw` means "stop the world", which means the time the program was stopped for to perform the garbage collection.
- There are 3 heaps in SGen, the nursery, major heap and the large object storage. The `size` values indicate the current size of those heaps.
- `promoted` indicates how much of the nursery has been promoted to the major heap

Comment: Great explanation you got here. Posted mine just to add a few other points but yours was excellent.

Answer (score 2):

CG stands for Garbage Collector.

The CG_MINOR is one of the Heaps used by **SGen** to allocate space for new objects, being **SGen** the default Garbage Collector used for Xamarin.

From the Xamarin Documentation:

> The Nursery – This is where new small objects are allocated. When the
>   nursery runs out of space, a minor garbage collection will occur. Any
>   live objects will be moved to the major heap.

You can get more information about the Xamarin Garbage Collection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/garbage-collection) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/memory-perf-best-practices#use-the-sgen-garbage-collector)